# Margin between plot and scale in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a problem with non-equal margined plots in matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fnx = lambda x: np.random.randint(5, 50, 10)
y = np.row_stack((fnx(0), fnx(0), fnx(0)))
x = np.arange(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
stacks = ax.stackplot(x, y)
```

results in such a graphic

[image]

How can I add the *same* margin to the x-axis like it is for the y-axis? So that the space between the scale and the colours for the x-axis is not 0, but as large as for the y-axis

Comment: I marked as duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159443/matplotlib-margins/43160169#43160169), which shows the same for a bar plot, but does directly apply here.

Comment: The marked duplicate does generate some white space beneath the stacked plot but I think the OP wants *equal* space (varying absolute x and y magnitudes). I prepared one solution but now the question is closed.

Comment: I would happily post the solution if the question is reopened and see if that's what OP wants

Comment: @Bazingaa thanks, that's exactly my question.

Comment: @MichaelDorner: So you are happy with the above answers? Or do you want the question to be reopened?

Comment: Second part, the existing answer does not cover the problem of the margin (they extend the scale).