# Set margins of a time series plotted with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the following code for generating a time series plot

```
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
series = pd.Series([np.sin(ii*np.pi) for ii in range(30)],
                   index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-31',
                                       periods=30))
series.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

I want to set an automatic limit for x and y, I tried using ax.margins() but it does not seem to work:

```
ax.margins(y=0.1, x=0.05)
# even with
# ax.margins(y=0.1, x=5)
```

[image]

What I am looking for is an automatic method like padding=0.1 (10% of whitespace around the graph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas and matplotlib seem to be confused rather often while collaborating when axes have dates. For some reason in this case `ax.margins` doesn't work as expected with the x-axis.

Here is a workaround which does seem to do the job, explicitely moving the xlims:

```py
xmargins = 0.05
ymargins = 0.1
ax.margins(y=ymargins)
x0, x1 = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(x0-xmargins*(x1-x0), x1+xmargins*(x1-x0))
```

Alternatively, you could work directly with matplotlib's plot, which does work as expected applying the margins to the date axis.

```
ax.plot(series.index, series)
ax.margins(y=0.1, x=0.05)
```

PS: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159443/matplotlib-margins) talks about setting `use_sticky_edges` to False and calling `autoscale_view` after setting the margins, but also that doesn't seem to work here.

```
ax.use_sticky_edges = False
ax.autoscale_view(scaley=True, scalex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ax.set_xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) and [ax.set_ylim](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html) to set the x and y limits of your plot respectively.

```py
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
series = pd.Series([np.sin(ii*np.pi) for ii in range(30)],
                   index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-31',
                                       periods=30))

# set xlim to be a between certain dates
ax.set_xlim((pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2019-01-31'))

# set ylim to be between certain values
ax.set_ylim((-0.5, 0.5))

series.plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: what I am looking for is an automatic method like padding=0.1 (10% of whitespace around the graph)

Comment: it seems like your solution is working for that (at least what i can see on the y-axis, the x-axis doesn't seem to be working).